# For handling the idxmax in xarray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have a xarray dataarray, which is defined as
, (see this
[link](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.idxmax.html))

```
xarray.DataArray (y:3,x:5)

array([[ 2.,  1.,  2.,  0., -2.],
       [-4., nan,  2., nan, -2.],
       [nan, nan,  1., nan, nan]])

Coordinates:
y (y)int64   -1 0 1
x (x)int64   0 1 4 9 16
```

If I want to find the first appearance of the value larger than 0 along the x dimension, I can use the command like `(array>0).idxmax(dim='x')`, which will return

```
xarray.DataArray 'x' (y: 3)

array([0, 4, 0])

Coordinates:
y (y)int64   -1 0 1
```

When I changed the threshold from 0 to 4, i.e., `(array>4).idxmax(dim='x')`, the expected results of the dataarray are `[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]`, becasue there are no value larger than 4 in the array. However, it returns the `[0,0,0]`.

I'm wondering if is there any way to solve my puzzle, i.e., return `[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]` rather than `[0,0,0]`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `.where` to substitute the `False` values with `nan`:

```py
import xarray as xr

array = xr.DataArray(
    [
        [2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, -2.0],
        [-4.0, np.nan, 2.0, np.nan, -2.0],
        [np.nan, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan],
    ],
    dims=["y", "x"],
    coords={"y": [-1, 0, 1], "x": np.arange(5.0) ** 2},
)

print(array.where(array > 0, np.nan).idxmax(dim="x"))
print(array.where(array > 4, np.nan).idxmax(dim="x"))
```

Prints:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'x' (y: 3)>
array([0., 4., 4.])
Coordinates:
  * y        (y) int64 -1 0 1

<xarray.DataArray 'x' (y: 3)>
array([nan, nan, nan])
Coordinates:
  * y        (y) int64 -1 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is little you can do to change the result.
The reason why it does not return nan is that it provides the correct result.
What you hand to the function idxmax is a boolean array that contains only zeros (False=0). So the function will return the first location of the largest value, which in this case is 0 at location 0.

What you could do instead is separating the two things:

1. Find the rows that contain values larger than your threshold. In case there are none you already have your failstate and can return NaN manually.
2. Only give those rows to the function so that you get the result only for those rows.